# Creating a new table on AWS Athena using an S3 Bucket csv table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to create a table to query on AWS Athena using an already existing table on my S3 Bucket. Despite using the tried and tested methods that I found online and have in fact used before too, I am still getting an error.

This is my current code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "database"."tablename" (
    column1 INT,
    column2 INT,
    column3 INT
)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim' = ',')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://s3-path/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification' = 'csv');
```

I am getting the following error:

```
mismatched input 'ROW'. Expecting: 'COMMENT', 'WITH', <EOF>
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors from Athena can be very vague. I just tested to create a table with test data:

```
column1,column2,column3
213,123,12
123,312,213
32,12,321
```

The query that works is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`tablename` (
  `column1` int,
  `column2` int,
  `column3` int
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim' = ',')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://s3-path/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification' = 'csv');
```